# UDP socket - list out of range when multiple clients are executed

Tags: python, python-2.7

server side

```
def address(x):
radd=(1,1)
f=open("name.list","rb")
for list in f:
    list=list.split()
    if(list[0]==x):
        radd=(list[1],list[2])
        break
return radd
f.close()

while True:
    data=recvfrom(1024)
    elif (data[0] == "send"):
    f=open("name.list","rb")
    add=address(data[1])
    radd=add[0] + " " + add[1]
    for list in f:
        name=list.split()
        if(int(addr[1])==int(name[2])):
            s.sendto(str(radd),addr)
            break
    else:
        s.sendto("not logged in ",addr)
    f.close()
```

client side

```
input="send usrname message"
s.sendto(input,server)
while True:
    if (input[0]=="send"):
        radd,add=s.recvfrom(1024)
        print radd
        radd=radd.split()
        print radd
        ip=radd[0]
        print ip
        port=int(radd[1])
        print port
        radd=(ip,port)
        s.sendto(input[2],radd)
        continue
```

the file store in format 
name ipaddress port

works fine on the first client, but when i open a second client and try to send a message to the first client it throws this error.the first client is able to send multiple messages to the second client. i used the same client.py file for invoking the client connections.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "client.py", line 30, in
>   
>       port=int(radd[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

to understand better i added print statement after each data conversion. it works perfectly fine if i omit the socket send function, but with the sendto function it ends up with an error and also the print does not print the expected result.

Comment: What is the format of the address you expect from the first socket? If it is of the form "ip:port", then you should use .split(":") instead of .split()

Comment: no its str(ip port)

Comment: Cold you post the output of the print statements? And, as a note, the line `f.close()` has to go before `return radd` in order to get executed (at the end of the server script).

Comment: i found what my problem was my recvfrom() buffer was storing previously received message and so the error ....   i need to know how to do a check for input from recvfrom() but if there is no input the program should move on to the next line. how do i do that ?

Comment: Check [socket.setblocking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking)

Comment: thanks for the help. i used threading to fix the problem.Using threading i was able to print message as and when received.

Answer (score 0):

```
port=int(radd[1]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error basically means that u are accessing lists 1st element but there is no element at this first position. radd list might contain only one element. Try to check this and accordingly modify your program code.